# Organizing a (6000,2) np array into 2-D grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, seaborn

I am having difficulties organizing or sorting a np array into 2-D Bins. I essentially have a 6000 by 2 datapoint array. I want to sort the array acording to it's x and y values (axis 1) over a 2-D plot ranging on either axis from 0 to 1. Meaning ultimately I need the counts of datapoints that land in the specific bin of a 10x10 grid (for a heatmap). However, I'm only interested in the values, not actually plotting the heatmap.

In a next step I would then have to organise/calculate the hits per grid for multiple 2-D arrays that are in a 3-D array and then calculate the std for each of the 10x10 bins depthwise in the 3_d array.

I would also preferre to saty in numpy rather than pandas.

I've tried using seaborn to create a heatmap and then to take the counts per grid out of that somehow, however that did not work as seaborn was just creating a heatmap based ión the individual values in the (6000,2) array on a (0,1) scale.

```
a = np.random.rand(6000,2)
b = np.random.rand(6000,2)

brick = np.dstack((a,b))

for i in range(len(brick[2])):
    sns.heatmap(brick[i], vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap = 'BuPu', annot=True, linewidths=0.1, cbar=True)
    plt.show()
```

One could oviously divide the data into the 10x10 grid with 100 if clauses, however there must be a simpler way?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear: 1/ you say have a 6000x2 array, but your code shows *two* of such arrays. 2/ You want to sort by x *and* y values; how does that work? Sort by x, then secondary by y? 3/ What *are* those x and y values; you mention them, but you never tell what axis these are on, and your code doesn't show any x and y. 4/ You want sort on axis 1, which seems to be the 2-element axis, which is rather odd to sort on. 5/ You mention counting points in bins, which is a histogram; do you mean that, you want a histogram?

Comment: The second array i just inserted to create a 3-D array, since thats what I would actually be working with, however just sorting the individual 2-D arrays is what I can't seem to manage. The x and y values are in either of the arrays but independent of oneanother. So the the array has a width of 2 axis[1] for x and y, with 6000 variations along axis[0].

Comment: I tried using a histogram, and would work fine if I'm only taking one of the vales (x or y) into account, however I would like to have it in dependance of eachother. :)

Comment: And numpy.histogram2d doesn't work for you?

Comment: let me give it a try. It might give me a picture of what I'm looking for, but I'm really interested in the exact values per grid to the go on with those values.

Comment: It looks to be getting me in the right direction thank you. I've not quite got the right spacing down though (will work on that).

Comment: You should post an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

So originally I was looking into using seaborn as seaborn can easily plot heatmaps and would then have used the values per grid to calc the std. However the organizing and sorting was my main issue. Using np.histogram2d was the key. I had previously only thought about 1D histograms, which in this case would'nt work because I first need to organize my grid to then either create a heatmap or calc the std.

```
check = []
heat_std = np.zeros(shape=(10,10))

a = np.random.rand(6000,2)
b = np.random.rand(6000,2)
c = np.random.rand(6000,2)

brick = np.dstack((a,b,c))

for i in range(brick.shape[2]):
    
    current = brick[:,:,i]
    check_pre = np.histogram2d(current[:,0], current[:,1], range = [[0, 1], [0, 1]],bins=10)
    check.append(np.asarray(check_pre[0]))
    
heat = np.dstack(check)    
np.std(heat, axis=2, dtype=None, out=heat_std, ddof=1)    
sns.heatmap(heat_std, vmin = 0, vmax = 1, cmap = 'BuPu', annot=True, linewidths=0.1, cbar=True)
plt.show()
```

This is what I came up with, I first create my grid values for each of the arrays in my 3D array and then dstack the grids to then calc the std and plot that as a heatmap.

Apologies for the rough start to my question. :)